# DataGridView Header text has center alignment but is not centered in the cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

Strange in that the header cell text is center aligned but the text position within the cell isn't. It's off to the left. The cells are aligned correctly but I've done that directly in the control.

```
       For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DGV.Columns
        col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter
    Next
```

Ideally I post an image of this but not sure how.

Comment: Does your data have spaces in it?  I know that I have to do a trim on data I retrieve because the text comes with trailing spaces.

Comment: Is it all the way to the left or left of center? I think the DataGridView allows for an icon to be shown on the headercell to indicate sort order